# How can I reuse the same view with different ViewModel in wpf prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a View for Insert an entity.

I want to edit the same entity and I want to reuse the same view for edit.

Now, How can I reuse the same view with different ViewModel for edit?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the `ViewModelLocator`, otherwise you wouldn't even have to ask the question.

So drop the view model locator here, navigate to the view model you want (`InsertViewModel` or `EditViewModel`) and assign the same view to both view models via data template.

Comment: Can't we assign the same view to two ViewModel via Prism?

Comment: We can, but only when using view model first, obviously. Otherwise, if you're given just the view, how would you decide which view model to create?

Comment: I know, We can use ViewModel first. I ask my question again:
Can't we assign the same view to (two) ViewModel via Prism?
for example, we have a view that called ViewA and we have two ViewModel that called ViewModelA and ViewModelB.
now I sometimes want to use ViewA with ViewModelA and sometimes Use ViewA with ViewModelB

Comment: Create a data template for ViewModelA that contains ViewA, create a data template for ViewModelB that contains ViewA, navigate to ViewModelA or ViewModelB using prism, it will show ViewA. That works. Create ViewA and map it to ViewModelA and navigate to ViewA using prism, it will create ViewModelA. That works, too. But navigating to ViewA twice and hoping it will create ViewModelA the first time and ViewModelB the second time, that will _not_ work.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need two different view models?

1. Just merge the properties in one viewmodel.
2. Or better still, break the view into different UserControls for each view model.

Comment: I have a View with two operations, so I want to have a view with two ViewModel for each operation

Comment: If the both the operations are running on the same data, make 2 methods on the same view model...i still don't understand why you need 2 view models?

Comment: I want to separate Create's codes and Edit's codes because I think it's clear than a ViewModel